# Question about the ring $A=k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$, Miles Reid section 4.4 example (iii)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am studying commutative algebra from the book of Miles Reid’s, and I stumbled upon this example, page 62 example (iii), which is have a very hard time understanding. The example:

> Consider the ring $A=k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$, and write $x,y \in A$ for the classes $X,Y$; the $A$ is not normal: it is not hard to see that $Frac A = k(t)$, where $t=y/x$, and $x=t^2$ and $y=t^3$, either of these relations show that $t$ is integral over $A$, but obviously $t$ not in $A$. Also $k[t]$ is normal since it is a UFD, so it is the integral closure of $A$ in $k(t)$.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on, I know all the terminology but I am really confused about this example. I cannot find the logical continuation between most of the arguments. Thank you very much.

EDIT: My main questions are:

1. What he means by : we write $x,y \in A$ for the classes $X,Y$;
2. Why $Frac A = k(t)$ with $t=y/x$?
3. How do we see that $t$ is integral over A?

Comment: "most of the arguments" is too vague. Do you understand that $A\simeq k[t^2,t^3]$? And is the last line about $k(t)$ clear for you?

Comment: @AnneBauval I don’t understand this example in general. Why is $Frac A = k(t)$? , why is $t$ integral over $A$?

Comment: I'm sure that by *the classes of $X$, $Y$* the author simply means the cosets. In other words $x=X+(Y^2-X^3)$ and $y=Y+(Y^2-X^3)$.

Comment: See also [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/658352/11619) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508378/11619). Don't know how much they help. It is kinda difficult to say something very helpful, because there seem to be gaps in your understanding of the basics, but we don't know exactly where they are.

Comment: I seem to have answered a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/500315/11619). Can you pinpoint the unclear steps?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for you answer! I wasn’t very sure about what Reid meant about the indeterminates $x,y$ , so I wanted to be sure. I think all my questions were answered by the answer below !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a commutative ring $A$ and an ideal $I$ of $A$, an element of the quotient ring $A/I$ is a coset of $I$, that is, a subset of $A$ of the form $a + I = \{a + b : b \in I\}$ for some $a \in A$. Specializing to this example, an element of $A = k[X, Y]/(Y^2 - X^3)$ is a coset of the ideal $(Y^2 - X^3)$. When Reid says to write $x, y \in A$ for the classes $X, Y$, this means to denote
$$\begin{aligned}
x &= X + (Y^2 - X^3) = \{X + (Y^2 - X^3) \cdot P : P \in k[X, Y]\}, \\
y &= Y + (Y^2 - X^3) = \{Y + (Y^2 - X^3) \cdot P : P \in k[X, Y]\}.
\end{aligned}$$
Algebraically, this means that $x$ and $y$ are indeterminates that also satisfy the relation $y^2 - x^3 = 0$ (and *only* this relation and those that logically follow from it), and the ring $A$ is generated over $k$ by $x$ and $y$.

Since the polynomial $Y^2 - X^3$ is irreducible and $k[X, Y]$ is a UFD, the ideal $(Y^2 - X^3)$ is prime, which means $A$ is an integral domain. Furthermore, $x \neq 0$ because $X \notin (Y^2 - X^3)$, which means we can consider the fraction $t = y/x$ as an element of $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$.

Note that $k(t) \subseteq \operatorname{Frac}(A)$ is the smallest field extension of $k$ containing $t$. Since $y^2 = x^3$, we have the following algebraic relations:
$$\begin{aligned}
t^2 &= y^2/x^3 = x^3/x^2 = x, \\
t^3 &= y^3/x^3 = y^3/y^2 = y.
\end{aligned}$$
So $x, y \in k(t)$, and therefore $A \subseteq k(t)$. Since $k(t)$ is a field containing $A$ and is itself contained in $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$, we must have $k(t) = \operatorname{Frac}(A)$.

Finally, for $t$ to be integral over $A$ means that $t$ is the root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$. And indeed, we have $t^2 - x = 0$ and $t^3 - y = 0$, and either of these shows $t$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: Perfect, this answer my questions! One last question, about the the last line: $k[t]$ is normal so it is the integral closure of $A$ in $k(t)$. What it is trying to say? Because we just showed that the integral closure of A in Frac(A)=k(t) is not A, i.e. A is not normal.

Comment: The last line is just noting that we've also obtained a description of the integral closure of $A$. Notice that $k[t]$ is a subring of $k(t)$ properly containing $A$.